# Is it possible to have a separate internal domain forest while still being connected to the corp net?

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hypervisor

If this has been answered or is totally newb, I apologize but I am a programmer and not a network guy. Please point me in the right direction.

What I am trying to do is create a separate forest called something like mydomain.com as a virtual domain, but keep the connection to the corp net so that I can transfer bits.

I am using windows server 2008 R2 as my desktop operating system, and I have 6 windows server 2008 R2 VMs running on its hypervisor (one of the VMs is a DNS/DC). I cannot establish a one-way trust with the corp net since there's too much red tape at my company.

**Is it possible to have my VMs running on my hypervisor while joined to the mydomain.com domain, but still keep corp net access through a second network adapter?**

My bad solution to this problem is to use snapshots. One snap shot with corp net access and the corresponding network adapter that I roll back to whenever I need to get net access, and then reset its network adapter to join mydomain.com once I have the bits transferred.

Is there a better way? I want to be able to set my own static IPs/etc, so having my own DNS/DC is necessary. There's a lot of red tape.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you need when you're accessing corp net? If you want some applications to authenticate itself as a domain user from your corp net while accessing some network resources when you're logging on as a user from your personal domain, try use `cmdkey` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243(v=ws.10).aspx which lets you specify which user you want to use when accessing a remote machine.